# windbg Type Failures after Windows update

Tags: .net, windows, debugging, clr, windbg

I recently enabled windows updates and after the updates my windbg environment is having Type Reference failures:

When using the !analyze -v command on dump files created after the updates. The ntdll symbols loads from the following path:

```
C:\symbol\wntdll.pdb\BBB0846A402C4052A16B67650BBFE6B02\wntdll.pdb
```

Thereafter I get the following Type Reference failures:

```
Type referenced: ntdll!_PEB
Type referenced: ntdll!_HEAP_FAILURE_INFORMATION 
Type referenced: nt!IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32
```

Whats very strange is that any dump files created prior to the Windows updates do not have these failures and the ntdll symbols loads from:

```
C:\symbol\wntdll.pdb\69DDFBCBBC14421D8CB974F8EDC414102\wntdll.pdb
```

I have used the dbh tool on both symbol files however only 69DDFBCBBC14421D8CB974F8EDC414102\wntdll.pdb displays information.  Can you please provide some insight. My windbg version is 6.3.9600.17298 from SDK 8.1.

[image: Type Reference Failure]

[image: Type Reference Success]

[image: dbh.exe no results]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a known issue relating to Windows 7 Kernel Symbols?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32278634/is-there-a-known-issue-relating-to-windows-7-kernel-symbols)

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32217038/ntdll-module-not-loading-correctly-in-windbg-but-why

Comment: I asked Microsoft, they currently investigate it and work on a solution to fix the symbols.